# ImageButton not showing to right of TextView in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, imagebutton

I need to have a **ImageButton** to right of **TextView** in **RelativeLayout** and I've tried this code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="fill_parent"
   android:background="#CC000000">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/quality"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:textColor="#666666"
    android:text="@string/default_bitrate" />


       <ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quality"
    android:src="@drawable/ico_arrow" >
</ImageButton>
```

The strange thing is that the ImageButton doesn't show with this scenario. I can see only the TextView.
Where's the mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your textview width to wrap content. setting it to match_parent, textview will take the entire width of the screen hence you can't see the image

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CC000000" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="@string/default_bitrate"
        android:textColor="#666666" />

     <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/quality"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quality"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_arrow" >
    </ImageButton>
```

Answer (score 2):

Dont make `TextView` width to match parent, either declare a width with dp or give the textview and imagebutton weights so that both of them can occupy space on the screen

Answer (score 1):

Change your xml with this:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="#CC000000">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/quality"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:textColor="#666666"
        android:text="@string/default_bitrate" />


    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/quality"
        android:src="@drawable/ico_arrow" >
    </ImageButton>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: great! it did the trick with android:layout_height="wrap_content" in TextView